# Select width changes when appended inside table?

Tags: html

I have initialized select width in CSS, when appended with an option, the width changes. How to avoid the change in width?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("select").append("<option>example.example.example</option>");
  });
 });
```

```css
select { width:100%; }
table { width:100%; }
div { width:200px; height:50px; background-color:grey; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <table>
  <tr><td>Label</td>
      <td><select>
           <option>Select</option>
          </select>
       </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the `width` to `100%`. It is inside a table, and tables will adjust to the size of it's contents. If you want it to be an exact size, you'll have to specify what size you want it to be. If you want it to be 100% of it's parent, you'll have to use a parent that is a div that has it's  width set. Table elements are flexible and are why you're getting this behavior.

If you want responsive behavior, you can usually use a responsive unit instead of tables or percent. `em` is a common responsive unit. [Here's more info on this unit from css-tricks.](http://css-tricks.com/why-ems) You could also use `vw` or several other units that are relative to screen size, but not to it's parent element

Comment: max-width (or) min-width does not help.

Comment: @YSuraj I just noticed that the select is in a table, I've changed my answer, please see.

Comment: So,  is it not possible to have a fixed size inside a table?

Comment: @YSuraj it is possible to be fixed, but 100% is not fixed, because the table will adjust to the size of the elements inside it. If you set the select to use `px`, `em`, or some other less parent relative unit, the table will not resize to fix select options.

Comment: but static measurement will not be helpful for a responsive page.

Comment: `em` is a responsive unit. https://css-tricks.com/why-ems/ You could also use `vw` or several other units that are relative to screen size, but not to it's parent element.

Comment: @YSuraj glad to hear it. If this answer was useful and answered your question, please upvote and click the green check mark to accept.

Comment: But not the above answer, post the 6th comment as answer.